# Error initializing server: OC4J administrator account is not configured

Tags: java

I am getting the following error message when trying to bring up ./oc4j service (`oc4j_extended_101350.zip`).

```
        [oracle@sc-ifactory01p bin]$ ./oc4j -start
        Starting OC4J from /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home ...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.682 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/dms.war...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.687 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/dms.war in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/dms
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.692 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/dms.war
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.693 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/JMXSoapAdapter-web.war...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.693 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/JMXSoapAdapter-web.war in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/JMXSoapAdapter-web
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.698 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/JMXSoapAdapter-web.war
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.736 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/jmsrouter.war...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.736 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/jmsrouter.war in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/jmsrouter
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.739 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/jmsrouter.war
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.746 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/connectors/datasources/datasources.rar...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.747 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/connectors/datasources/datasources.rar in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/connectors/datasources/datasources
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.748 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/connectors/datasources/datasources.rar
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.749 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/connectors/OracleASjms/OracleASjms.rar...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.749 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/connectors/OracleASjms/OracleASjms.rar in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/connectors/OracleASjms/OracleASjms
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.760 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/connectors/OracleASjms/OracleASjms.rar
        Aug 1, 2014 2:09:28 PM com.evermind.server.XMLDataSourcesConfig parseRootNode
        INFO: Legacy datasource detected...attempting to convert to new syntax.
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.778 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/javasso.ear...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.778 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/javasso.ear in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/javasso
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.780 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/javasso.ear
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.786 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/javasso/javasso-web.war...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.786 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/javasso/javasso-web.war in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/javasso/javasso-web
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.790 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/javasso/javasso-web.war
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.793 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol.ear...
        2014-08-01 14:09:28.793 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol.ear in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol
        2014-08-01 14:09:29.281 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol.ear
        2014-08-01 14:09:29.283 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol/ascontrol.war...
        2014-08-01 14:09:29.283 NOTIFICATION Unjar /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol/ascontrol.war in /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol/ascontrol
        2014-08-01 14:09:30.148 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking /apps/prd/oracle/10.1.3.5.0/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol/ascontrol.war
        14/08/01 14:09:30 Error initializing server: OC4J administrator account is not configured correctly. Please make sure that at least one administration account is created and configured correctly.
        14/08/01 14:09:30 Fatal error: server exiting
```

I am running this on RHEL 6.5 physical 64bit platform. I have pointed `jdk1.6.0_45` for JAVA_HOME.

I am able to bring it up on a VM which has same RHEL 6.5 64bit platform. I tried everything that I and google can think of but can't seems to figure this one out.

There are some users reported to add hostname on /etc/hosts file which I have already tried but didn't work on my physical system.

Let me know if you have suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-installation of OS before applying any specific configuration I was able to start oc4j service. After narrowing it down to which configuration was exactly causing this not to start was came out to be Ethernet bonding. I had a kickstart script which was also doing bonding. The ifcfg-ethx also contains lot of details such UUID and things that would not basically was not really required for my environment. After cleaning up the all ifcfg-* and able to bring up bonding with oc4j service.